# Share code that uses Entity Framework between .NET 4.8 and .NET 6 projects

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

We have 2 projects:

1. .NET Core Web API that targets .NET 6 and references some .NET Standard 2.1 libraries.
2. .NET 4.8 App.

Both projects have code that overlaps (duplicates) itself.
Every time we make changes to one app, we need to make changes to the other.

So I was given a task to make a library that could be referenced by both apps and remove code duplication that way.

I researched the subject and found out that both apps could reference .NET Standard 2.0 library.

That would be fine, but code to be copied to new .NET Standard 2.0 library uses Entity Framework. Entity Framework can only be used with .NET Standard 2.1 library.

So my question is: how do I share code that uses Entity Framework between two kinds of projects: .NET 6 & .NET 4.8. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: IMO: you don't - EF6 and EF Core are sufficiently different that limiting yourself to the common surface area gives you the worst of both

Comment: I'd just stick with EF6.4 (_not_ EFCore) - as that is compatible with both .NET Fx 4.8 and .NET Core 3.1+ (via .NET Standard 2.1). You'd need to use multi-targeting in your `.csproj` to make it work (which doubles your build-times... fun) - but otherwise it works - it's how my org's managing its .NET Fx 4.8-to-.NET 6 migration.

Comment: It's not a matter of .NET Standard 2.0 or 2.1. You can't use EF Core in .NET Framework projects, only in .NET Core projects. The last version of Entity Framework "Classic" was 6.4. was released 4 years ago with a minor update, 6.4.4, 3 years ago. And 6.4 itself wasn't all that different from earlier 6.x versions.

Comment: What are the applications doing? In ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core migration projects it's common to extract parts as ASP.NET Core API projects that get called by both the old and new code. That has overhead though which means the new API project should have to do more than act as a database API to justify (and reduce) the overhead.